# Simple HTML generation via PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an array of HTML tags:

```
class sampleHTML {
    public function __construct( $tag = [] ) {
        $html = [
            [
                'type' => 'p',
                'class' => '.sample-class',
                'content' => 'Sample content'
            ],
            [
                'type' => 'div',
                'class' => '.sample-class-2',
                'content' => 'Sample content 2'
            ],
        ];

        foreach( $html as $tag ) {
            new Tag( $tag );
        }
    }
}
```

I want to generate HTML from the array. So far I have following class to generate the HTML.

```
class Tag {

    public $tag;

    public function __construct( $tag = [] ) {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        switch ($tag['type']):
            case 'p':
                $this->render_p();
                break;
            case 'div':
                $this->render_div();
                break;
        endswitch;
    }

    private function render_p() {
        echo '<p class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</p>';
    }

    private function render_div() {
        echo '<div class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</div>';
    }

}
```

It's OK but I want to make my codes better by the **use of sub classes** and **removal of switch**. Similar to following:

```
class Tag {

    public $tag;

    public function __construct( $tag = [] ) {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        $this->render()
    }

    public function render() {};

}

class P extends Tag {
    public function render() {
        echo '<p class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</p>';
    }
}

class Div extends Tag {
    public function render() {
        echo '<div class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</div>';
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to use sub classes without switch?
2. If so, how to call the `render` method of child class dynamically based on tag type.

Comment: Strikes me that creating an object (instance of $tag) and doing all its work in the constructor then dereferencing the instance is a very inefficient way to write a program

Comment: @symcbean if possible explain more and provide a sample of efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd say it is an overhead to create classes for each tag type (until it's just a program for studying).

Basically, you may use some kind of pattern, like [Factory](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) or [Strategy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).

So I'd go with something like this:

```
interface TagInterface
{
    public function render();
}

class TagFactory
{
    public static function createTag($tag)
    {
        $class = ucfirst($tag['type']) . 'Tag';
        return new $class($tag);
    }
}

abstract class Tag implements TagInterface
{
    protected $tag;

    public function __construct(array $tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
}

class PTag extends Tag
{
    public function render()
    {
        echo '<p class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</p>';
    }
}

class DivTag extends Tag
{
    public function render()
    {
        echo '<div class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</div>';
    }
}
```

And then in your code:

```
foreach($html as $tag ) {
    /** @var TagInterface $tag */
    $tag = TagFactory::createTag($tag);
    $tag->render();
}
```

This is a correct architecture for tasks like yours. But, I repeat, it's only okay for studying. In real life things would be much simpler, so @Syscall's answer is actually what it should look like.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote this simple example for my question here. I am working on a form builder. Some of the fields have complex html so I need to keep them in separate classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could made dynamic instances using `new $var()`, and remove your switch.

```
foreach( $html as $tag ) {
   $class = ucfirst($tag['type']);
   $obj = new $class($tag); // will calls new P() or new Div()
   //$obj->render();
}
```

Full code :

```
class sampleHTML {
    public function __construct() {
        $html = [
            [
                'type' => 'p',
                'class' => '.sample-class',
                'content' => 'Sample content'
            ],
            [
                'type' => 'div',
                'class' => '.sample-class-2',
                'content' => 'Sample content 2'
            ],
        ];
        foreach( $html as $tag ) {
            $class = ucfirst($tag['type']);
            new $class( $tag );
        }
    }
}
class Tag {
    public $tag;
    public function __construct( $tag = [] ) {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        $this->render();
    }
    public function render() {}
}
class P extends Tag {
    public function render() {
        echo '<p class="' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</p>';
    }
}
class Div extends Tag {
    public function render() {
        echo '<div class="' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</div>';
    }
}
new sampleHTML();
```

Outputs :

```
<p class=".sample-class">Sample content</p><div class=".sample-class-2">Sample content 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it does the job. Also looking for other possible solution.

Comment: @user3631047 I understand :) Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use sub classes without switch?

Yes! You can even do it without switch AND without subclasses.
You already have the tag type as string, so you can make use of it:

```
class Tag {

    public $tag;

    public function __construct( $tag = [] ) {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        $this->render();
    }

    private function render() {
        echo '<'.$this->tag['type'].' class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</'.$this->tag['type'].'>';
    }
}
```

This way, there is no need for subclasses like `Div extends Tag`.

> how to call the render method of child class dynamically based on tag
>   type?

Although with my solution you wouldn't need subclasses, I'm gonna answer that question too.
If you want to call a specific render function from a subclass, define/override the function in that subclass itself

```
class Tag {
    // constructor

    // render 
    function render(){
        // standard tag html
        echo '<'.$this->tag['type'].' class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '">' . $this->tag['content'] . '</'.$this->tag['type'].'>';
    }
}

class Table extends Tag {
    // render (this overrides the render function of Tag)
    function render(){
        echo '<table class"' . $this->tag['class'] . '"><th><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td></th><tbody></tbody></table>';
    }
}

class Div extends Tag {
    // no render function here
    // this way Div uses the render function of Tag 
}
```

**Edit:**
If you need subclasses (because some tags are built in a completely different way) but you still have basic tags like `p` od `div` you could define overriding `render()`-functions for only those who have a different html. If it's a tag with standard html you can leave out the `render()` function in that subclass so it will use the `render()` function of the Tag class. I edited the code above to represent that idea.

Comment: I need to use sub classes. I like the way you explained override. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit since you say you do need subclasses.